# How can i enable multi category filter selection in Jquery filter

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating website for my client. In wordpress Portfolio by default I can select one category in filter. How can I select multi category in filter.

[image: Example showing multi select]

What code should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Use (+) for multiple categories

This is a sample code

```
<ul>
    <?php
    global $post;

    $myposts = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'category_name'=>'oranges + apples'
    ));

    if ( $myposts ) {
        foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : 
            setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php
        endforeach;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```